# How to fetch the data on the basis of multiple ids?

Tags: mongodb, go

Here I'm fetching the data from the database mongodb using golang. Suppose I have an `Id` attribute and i want to receive the data on the basis of this id and it was easy by passing the id attribute in the query like below:-

```
 c.Find(bson.M{"_id": 1}).One(&data)
```

If the id is given 1. but I have an case that i have find two or more at  one time on the basis of the ids that it will returns the array of the ids like "_id":[1,2,3] then How will I retrieve the data from that ids. Can anyone help for if.

**EDITED**

IS this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428281/querying-mongodb-from-golang-using-the-id-stored-in-an-array) solve my problem.

Thanks

Comment: @icza Can you tell me for this what method from (POST,GET, PUT, DELETE) is used means what method should I have to use for better result